# Team Foundation Server Build with password protected codesigning fails

Tags: tfs, build, continuous-integration, code-signing, delay-sign

I'm trying to setup a continuous integration build on TFS 2008. In the project I want to build I use a key for signing. This key uses a password. I can't get it to build, because during the build TFS wants to show a dialog which can't be shown. I think I need to build the project by hand on the server, but only the TFS explorer and build parts are installed on the server. Any suggestions on how to get my project to build properly?

This is the error given by TFS:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7):
>   error MSB4018: The "ResolveKeySource"
>   task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   Showing a modal dialog box or form
>   when the application is not running in
>   UserInteractive mode is not a valid
>   operation. Specify the
>   ServiceNotification or
>   DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
>   notification from a service
>   application.    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window
>   owner)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource.ResolveAssemblyKey()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ResolveKeySource.Execute()

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This [blog post](http://ozgrant.com/2008/03/13/strong-name-your-assemblies-with-team-build-using-a-private-key/) below details the exact steps

**Setup Key Files**

Create a password-protected private/public key pair (KeyPair.pfx) using the Visual Studio “Signing” tab within a project’s properties
Extract the public key from the key pair and copy it to a separate file (Key.snk)
sn.exe -p KeyPair.pfx Key.snk

Copy the KeyPair.pfx to your build server. I use C:\Program Files\MSBuild\KeyFile.pfx, because it can then be accessed by the $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) MSBuild property.
Move the KeyPair.pfx file to a safe & secure location. Keep the password secret as well.
Copy the Key.snk to a shared location where your developers can access it.
Setup Projects for Signing

For each assembly that you want to sign:

1. Open the Project Properties | Signing page
2. Select the [X] Sign the assembly checkbox.
3. Select the [X] Delay sign only checkbox.
4. Select  from the key file dropdown.
5. Browse to the shared location and select the Key.snk file
6. The snk file will be copied to each project directory that you assign it to
7. Copy the key file from one of your projects into Solution Items so that you can use it for the test run configuration

**Setup Test Run Configuration for Re-Signing**

If you want to instrument your assemblies and enable Code Coverage for your unit tests, then you need to specify a key file for re-signing.

Open the LocalTestRun.testrunconfig file
On the Code Coverage tab, select the key as the Re-Signing key file

**Disable Strong-Name Verification on Developer Workstations**

Since you are delay-signing with only the public key, .NET CLR assembly verification will fail with assemblies built locally. When the verification fails you won’t be able to run or debug the assemblies.

To overcome this in development, you need to disable strong-name verification for assemblies that you build locally and delay-sign with your public key.

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt
Type:
`sn.exe -tp Key.snk`

This will output some data including the token.

Type:
`sn -Vr *,YOUR_KEY_TOKEN`

example: `sn -Vr *,0123456789abcdef`

This will disable strong name verification for all assemblies signed with your public key.
You can list current settings for strong name verification with:
sn -Vl

**Installing the Private Key for Team Build**

Since the private key (Key.pfx) is password protected – Team Build cannot access it. Thanks to [Nagaraju Palla’s Blog: Using Password Protected Signing Keys in Team Build](http://blogs.msdn.com/nagarajp/archive/2005/11/08/490501.aspx), we have a solution.

Logon to the Team Build server as the build service account
Open the project in Visual Studio
Build the project in Visual Studio
You will be prompted for the password to the private key file.
Enter the password
Close Visual Studio & Log off
The private key file is now installed in the build service account’s local certificate store and Team Build can access it without prompting for the password again. This certificate store is as secure as the build service account’s password. (Hint: Make it just as strong as your keyfile’s password)

**Updating TFSBuild.proj Build Script**

Team Build has access to the private keyfile and password. This allows it to fully-sign the assemblies.

To override the project settings and instruct Team Build to use the private keyfile and disable partial-signing, we need to set the CustomPropertiesForBuild property in TFSBuild.proj

Check-out your TFSBuild.proj build script
Search for the placeholder  property (near line 130 by default)
Replace it with the following:

  SignAssembly=true;DelaySign=false;AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile=$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Key.pfx

Check-in your changes
Queue a build
Verifying Team Build output

To check that Team Build has correctly strongly named your assemblies, you can use the sn.exe utility to verify the strong name signature.

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt
Type:
sn.exe -vf assemblyname.dll

You can also verify all your assemblies at the same time:

Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt
Type:
FOR %a IN (*.dll) DO sn.exe -vf %a

Comment: Great answer, Thanks! but I run in some troubles when trying to build the project manualy to get the key installed. I don't have the "normal" visual studio installed, only tfs explorer and tfs build. does this mean I have to install team dev in order to build my project only once?

Comment: I don't get an error. Except for the MSB4018 from my question when letting tfs do the building. I got stuck after opening the project in Visual studio on the build server. The entire project is grayed out, because I only have the shell with the build services installed on the server. I think I'm overseeing something here ;)

Comment: Surely you don't need to open the project on the build server as your MSBuild script will do the build?

Comment: Fixed it… had to run MSBuild from the command line ;) MSBuild is stored in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\FrameWork\v3.5 by default, had to do a search for that. Got the whole search and just run MSBuild without any parameters from the \TeamBuildTypes\CI directory where the build script was located. Thanks again!

Comment: What if you are using Visual Studio Online(Microsofts hosted TFS solution)? You don't get access to a build machine that you can log onto.