# Delay signing during development and not on the build server

Tags: .net, msbuild, code-signing, delay-sign

I've got a few projects that are configured for delay signing on development machines, and I want to configure the build server so that it doesn't delay sign release builds.

How can I do this?

I'm using VSTS/TFS.

---

The question is different, [but the answer is what I need.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056997/team-foundation-server-build-with-password-protected-codesigning-fails/1057108#1057108)

Comment: Please close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056997/team-foundation-server-build-with-password-protected-codesigning-fails

Comment: I'm closing but not because its a dupe (it is NOT), but because the top answer in that question contains the information needed -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056997/team-foundation-server-build-with-password-protected-codesigning-fails/1057108#1057108

Comment: I misclicked the close reason, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to best deal with this question and still let it come up in search results for people looking for a solution...  If you want to do this, here's your answer:

[Team Foundation Server Build with password protected codesigning fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056997/team-foundation-server-build-with-password-protected-codesigning-fails/1057108#1057108)

I'll accept this answer sometime in the future.